# Font rendering issue on hover/click/jquery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

building a mobile site using bootstrap 3 which makes use of the collapse js plugin.

My issue is that when you hover over the font in the collapse (it's worth noting that this happens with system fonts and is not just a web-font issue, it's just easier to show with a webfont) or click the font it changes in appearance. Parts of the font are removed or the size changes. I'm not sure why this is happening and I've tried the following:

- -webkit-font-smoothing
- text-rendering
- adding a fixed line height
- backface-visiblity

However, none of those work. I'm running out of ideas and while it's harder to show in a screenshot it is 100% a big and noticeable issue when interacting with the site.
[image]

I'm assuming it's something to do with the collapse jquery but I can't find anything in the bootstrap repo, on here or from a general google search (hard thing to search for haha) so any help would be appreciated. I don't have much code related to the fonts but:

```
  .panel-tap {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

The panel has some padding but this isn't altered during the animation, nor are any styles added during the animation (only class names are added to display/hide the content below.

I can't post a link to the site but hopefully this is enough info.
Thanks

***edit: Worth noting that I've tried removing all styles associated with it (i.e position) and tried adding specific styles to make sure it isn't being overridden across the site (i.e adding font-weights, line-heights, borders etc)***

***edit2: This doesn't happen all the time, it stops after a few seconds or a few clicks, it's totally inconsistent***

***edit3: Disabled the animation/jquery side of collapse and it still does it***

Comment: Can we see a JSFiddle?

Comment: @risk The issue doesn't appear on fiddle (although I have attached all styles in an external stylesheet) so it must be something to do with the js on my page but the code can still be inspected to look for any potential errors http://jsfiddle.net/8pdM7/

Comment: I added bootstrap.js to your fiddle and this seems to work well : http://jsfiddle.net/9enx7/ So the problem has to be due to some external js (or css) code. If @discoliam answer didn't worked, I can't help you more without a fiddle reproducing the error or, at least, any code which may cause the bug..

Answer (score 0):

Some Ideas:

- Have you tried setting all the CSS annimation properties to `0`/`none`. It might be picking something up from a parent/bad selector elsewhere.
- Double checked there is no CSS for `:active` or `:focus`. Or maybe a span around the text that has a relative `font-size` ( `em`, `%` etc)
- I remember having trouble with something similar and `position:relative;`. Can you wrap a `span` around the text and give it `position:static;`
- Is there an active class or something that might be causing the issue?

Thats all I can think of at the mo. But might help.

Comment: Thanks, Don't actually use any css animation on the collapse as of yet, it just shows and hides with no transition/animation - it also occurs before the animation is triggered. I'll have a look for the :Active and :focus although I couldn't see any in browser - I tried removing relative and it gave me the same results but I will try the span around that now. No active class as again, it happens to all and happens before the animations are triggered